# How to compute spectral lines from NIST term data?

Tags: laser, spectroscopy, hydrogen, data, term-symbols

We know, that [Hydrogen has line of 21cm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line) in space. How can we (and can we) find the energy levels, producing these lines in [NIST energy levels database](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html)?

Other example. We know that [Nd:YAG laser emits on 1064 nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nd:YAG_laser). Can we (and how) compute this number from Nd data?

If we learn term names from some picture like this:

[image]

we know, that we need transition from $^4F_{3/2}$, which is 11290 $cm^{-1}$ and $^4I_{11/2}$, which is 1880 $cm^{-1}$, according to [NIST data](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?encodedlist=XXT2&de=0&spectrum=Nd3&submit=Retrieve%20Data&units=0&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&conf_out=on&term_out=on&level_out=on&unc_out=1&j_out=on&lande_out=on&perc_out=on&biblio=on&temp=).

If we compute,

```
1/(11290 - 1880)/100*1000000000
```

we get

```
1062.7
```

What I did wrong? How to get correct value of 1064?

Comment: It seems pretty close to me. I would guess that the small difference is due to perturbations of the neodymium energy levels by the nearby yttrium, aluminum, and oxygen atoms.

Comment: Problem is values given above are barycentra of bands. However garnets are known for high Stark splitting. It can be around 500 cm-1, while difference between what you got and what you wan is just 11 cm-1. There is no significant difference between the two. Besides the values given by NIST are either for ion in vacuum, or in aqueous solution, and they can shift for real crystals, although it's generally weaker effect than the Stark splitting.